# How to debug reference error when a library is not being loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

For example I am getting a `reference error L is not defined` where L is leaflet. I have followed [their tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html), and here is what I have just before the end of my body:

```
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/secretid/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
      maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);
</script>
```

I've checked and the hyperlink to the js file works.

Comment: Perhaps the browser has not loaded everything? Try to hang that code into the proper on load event.

Comment: A [quick test](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/oivBd) demonstrates that it works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure all script have already loaded, use onload callback like this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
     var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
     L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/secretid/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a     href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a     href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
 maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is fine advice but it should not be necessary. Unless steps are taken to prevent it, `<script>` contents are loaded and evaluated synchronously.